# Android 1.5/1.6 issue with style and autogenerated R.java file

Tags: java, android

I'm having strange issue with R.java file and styles defined in my resources.

Here's some code:

In res/values/strings.xml:

```
<style parent="android:Theme.Dialog" name="PopupWindowStyle">
<item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/bg1</item>
<item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
</style>
```

In AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity
    android:name=".RegisterScreen"
    android:icon="@drawable/ico" 
    android:label="@string/applicationName" 
    android:theme="@style/PopupWindowStyle"
    android:configChanges="locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|fontScale">
</activity>
```

In autogenerated gen/.../R.java:

```
public static final class style {
    public static final int PopupWindowStyle=0x7f090000;
}
```

After some changes in the project, eclipse changed autogenerated value for `PopupWindowStyle` from 0x7f080000 to 0x7f090000. After that, on Android 1.5, `RegisterScreen` activity is displayed without `PopupWindowStyle` style - there is an error displayed in logcat:

`Skipping entry 0x7f090000 in package table 0 because it is not complex!`

On Android 1.6 however everything works fine - `PopupWindowStyle` works like it was before it's integer value has changed.

I was testing this issue, by reverting the source code to older revisions. I can confirm, that this problem started occurring after src code commit, which changed two files completely unrelated to this part of code - and an autogenerated R.java file.

Any idea what could cause that?

Comment: no idea yet but what is in your mainfest file ie minSdk and targetSDk tags?

Comment: @Fred: minSdkVersion="3" - there's no targetSdk tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I kinda solved the issue, but I still don't know why it needs to be that way on Android 1.5.

It seems that it was caused by another file: res/values/colors.xml which had only this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="threattypelabel">#4f83cc</color>
    <color name="threattypebg">#eeeeee</color>
</resources>
```

After moving those color tags back to res/values/strings.xml it suddenly works fine (tested few times back and forward).

Answer (score 1):

I too faced this error today. In my case, there are 2 projects - one an app and the other library. Both contain strings. In the code of library project, the generated R class file had same integral indexes of some strings as that of the app project.

I had to change default.properties of app project to make it included
android.library.reference.1=libraryprojectlocation

where libraryprojectlocation is the relative disk location of the library project.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I had a string array in a res/values/array.xml. When I moved the string array to res/values/strings.xml, the app ran fine. Looking at the android dev site http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html however
they make it clear that it's okay to have more than one xml file in res/values, and in fact they suggest it. So I tried an experiment, I changed the name of the offending xml file to arrays.xml, note the extra "s" at the end, and it worked. I also restarted my avd and eclipse. And I also used the gui to build the xml file instead of typing it in.